# WPF DataGrid - on row selection/lose focus prevent color change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to prevent my program from changing row's color when datagrid loses focus and has one of the rows selected. The code I have right now is:

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush 
            x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
                     Color="Red"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Im looking for something like

> Color="Remain Unchanged"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to customize the `IsSelected` property trigger / multi-trigger for the `DataGridCell` style, as below:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And then apply your custom style:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}"/>
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Adding full XAML:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication333.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication333"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="248" Width="113" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="143,116,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I added full XAML to my post, please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: I somehow managed to make it work before your edit, nonetheless your answer fully solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of late, but I want to share my approach. Since at this year 2023, I cannot find any solution on the internet that work.

Short answer:

```
    private void DataGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DataGrid)?.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

But if you do care about selection, you listen to two events:

```
    private void DataGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid? dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg == null)
            return;
        
        // Try to store indexes like row indexes, column indexes.
        // And then just remove selections
        // If you want to know what was selected before it lost focus,
        // you could create properties for the indexes you stored.

        dg.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void dataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Restore selection if needed
    }
```

So, the idea is not to have "inactive selection" at all. You store and then remove all the selections and then when you got back focus, restore the selection.

Be careful when you have something that depends on *selection changed* because this solution will raise a lot of selection changed events.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me...

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <!--DISPLAY CONTENT IN MIDDLE-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <!--style triggers added to keep the selection color active on lost focus in datagrid-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#005691"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#005691"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```