# How to set transparent background for the selected data grid row?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styling

If I use a normal color like Red, it works. But if I use Transparent, it shows up as white when not focused, and blue when focused. Is there a special setting I have to enable for the window?

[image]

Here is the minimum code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void SetField<T> ( ref T field, T value, string propertyName )
        {
            if ( !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals ( field, value ) )
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins;
        public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get => _coins; set => SetField ( ref _coins, value, nameof ( _coins ) ); }
        public ICollectionView CollectionView;

        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            this.Coins = new ObservableCollection<Coin> ( );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 1", 1 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 2", 2 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 3", 3 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 4", 4 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 5 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 6 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 7 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 8 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 9 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 10 ) );
            this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 5", 11 ) );

            this.DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent ( );
        }
    }

    public class Coin
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int PNL { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Color2 { get; set; }

        public Coin ( string symbol, int pnl )
        {
            this.Symbol = symbol;
            this.PNL = pnl;

            Random rnd = new Random ( );
            Color c = Color.FromRgb ( ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ) );

            this.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush ( c );
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="myMainWindow"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Topmost="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Height="426">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                </Trigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=" "/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="PNL %"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Color2}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="12"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="13"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="14"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Min %"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeMinutelyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Net BTC/m"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#75001D" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" " Visibility="Hidden" MinWidth="0" Width="10" CanUserSort="False"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.UnitPrice" Binding="{Binding Path=PNL}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.Profit" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitDisplay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.TotalProfitInUSDDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL %" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.ProfitPercentage" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageDisplay}"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="PriceChangeInPercentHourly" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="PriceChangeInPercentMinutely" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="60" SortMemberPath="LastHourVolumeInBtc">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=TotalSellVolumePercentage, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastHourVolumeInBtcDisplay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="60" SortMemberPath="LastMinuteVolumeInBtc" Binding="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeInBtcDisplay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could it be that the window background is causing this? Can you set the background of window to Red or Transparent and see if that affects what you see.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I just tried this, it's the same, not sure what's going on.

Comment: So your main issue is with when it's not selected or when selected? Well either way this looks like a `DataGridRow` style issue. I would suggest to edit in Blend and override the template. It could be the same issue as with Button. There is a border in there somewhere that is not playing ball. Give that a go and see what happens.

Comment: @XAMlMAX when it's selected. When it's not selected it looks correct. It also changes selection color when the window is not in focus so I have to change that too. I dont want focus to change selection color.

Comment: I see, I will have a look and try to reproduce this (it's 10 am where I am), this afternoon. I think once you override the template it will fix it.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thanks a lot I appreciate it, I tried everything I can think of, not sure why this happens.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266323/2029607)? In that example you will find complete datagridrow style which you can customise.

Comment: I didnt see it, let me try it today.

Comment: Fill=transparent means no fill, which is what you get (you see what's underneath, in my case white or yellow from RowStyleWithAlternation). What do you mean by "How to set transparent background for the selected data grid row?"

Comment: @SimonMourier: I mean the selection is visible as outline as the code does but doesn't override the current item background colors, i.e. the selection is transparent. I just want selection to outline the current item, not change any other colors, both in focused and not focused window.

Comment: The data grid cell have no defined background. Try to add `<Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Whatever" />` (Whatever can be Transparent) in `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">`

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks that seemed to set the background but it also overrides the alternating row colors for example. Because I am overriding cell colors based on various binding, all I need is to have the selection state to leave these colors alone.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't alternate colors or maybe I missed something.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I didn't realize the alternate colors would work differently with your solution so I will try to create a better code sample. Thx!

Comment: @SimonMourier: I updated code with alternating rows, I don't know but I am still white. Basically what I am doing is to have the base colors to alternate while some cells I want to color green/red depending on values, but on top of this if there is selection, to only outline the row, not override the existing BG colors, whether the window is in focus or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like this:

[image]

I did this by adding transparent background to DataGridCell's properties and removing yellow background from DataGridRow on IsSelected trigger

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="test"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Topmost="True"
    Height="426">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>




    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Color2}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkKhaki"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkMagenta" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}" 
              SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
              RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" " MinWidth="0" Width="10" CanUserSort="False"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Symbol" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Symbol}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL %" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Color}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Profit"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid></Window>
```

**UPDATE**

After the update in the question, I just removed

`<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>` from

`<Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">`  in the original code pasted in the question itself and this is how the grid looks for me

[image]

Is this what you are looking for or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Complete MainWindow.xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="myMainWindow"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Topmost="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Height="426">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>-->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
            </Trigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=" "/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="11"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="12"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="13"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyBackColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="14"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Min %"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeMinutelyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Net BTC/m"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#75001D" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" " Visibility="Hidden" MinWidth="0" Width="10" CanUserSort="False"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.UnitPrice" Binding="{Binding Path=PNL}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.Profit" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitDisplay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.TotalProfitInUSDDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL %" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.ProfitPercentage" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageDisplay}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="PriceChangeInPercentHourly" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="PriceChangeInPercentMinutely" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Market.PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="60" SortMemberPath="LastHourVolumeInBtc">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=TotalSellVolumePercentage, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastHourVolumeInBtcDisplay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="60" SortMemberPath="LastMinuteVolumeInBtc" Binding="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeInBtcDisplay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid></Window>
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this with alternating row colors, it doesn't seem to work. Can you please give it a try? I updated OP.

Comment: Hey, I tried with the new code and updated my answer. Could you take a look at the screenshot and let me know if you want the grid to look like this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, when I am copy pasting your code, it doesnt work. Is it possible to add your changes to my code so I can copy paste and also diff the changes? Otherwise it's a bit hard to follow the changes, it's more error prone for me.

Comment: Posted the complete code. It has two lines that are commented out and is working fine for me. I also noticed that your selected grid row behaves differently when the grid is not in focus(numbers in 1st cell go black in color). I don't know if you want to fix this as well but can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710351/wpf-datagrid-on-row-selection-lose-focus-prevent-color-change. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! Btw why does the selected row also look shifted? Is it possible to fix this also? I posted about it but not reply.

Comment: It's probably because of the separator which already occupies some space in leftmost region of the 1st column. when a row is selected, the blue selection rectangle starts after the separator in the left side of the 1st column. I added code to add negative margin, you could also just set the border thickness on the left side to zero. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, it really works. But one thing I noticed is when I lose focus in my window (by clicking on another app, the foreground color becomes black. Why is this? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229921/discussion-between-barkha-jain-and-joan-venge).

Answer (score 1):

you made everything - DataGridRow.Background, DataGridCell.Background - transparent

after selection you can see white DataGrid Background (#FFF) - through row and cells

to fix the issue, remove setter for Background in IsSelected trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>-->
</Trigger>
```

it will ensure that one of previous triggers works:

```
<Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it doesn't work. Actually I had to change the OP code because there is yet another background coloring that happens on some cells.

Comment: So not sure why Selection uses Alternate background colors but if it's not selected, the individual cell background is used.

Comment: @JoanVenge, another bg works only for one column. try `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />` in `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">`

Comment: thanks I just tried it but it's the same color as removing transparent bg as in your example.